# Yii showing validation errors in two dates

Tags: php, yii, validation

In Yii I am writing a small application called Invoice Application. In that I have two fields called `Invoice Issue Date` and `Due Date`. I want validation for both of the input date fields so that `Due Date` must be greater than `Invoice Issue Date`. So I made the following rule in the model:

```
public function rules (){
    array('due_date','compare','compareAttribute'=>'invoice_issue_date',
          'operator'=>'>',
          'allowEmpty'=>false,'message'=>'Due Date must be greater then Invoice Issue Date.'),
}
```

It is working fine but when in one field there is a two digit date (10 to 31) and another has a single digit date (1 to 9) then this validation not working at all. Can someone tell me what is wrong here? Any help and suggestions are welcome.

**UPDATE**

For dates I am using `CJuiDatePicker` to enter date fields.

Comment: Which field would have the single digit date and which the two digit date in order for this not to work?

Comment: Also what do you mean by one digit and two digit? Is that the real values of the date fields or is it just shorthand for a date format?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think, this is a common mistake many PHP developers do.

```
if( '2012-07-23' > '2012-08-17' ) 
// this is equivalent to comparing two strings , not dates
```

correct way is ...

```
if( strtotime('2012-07-23') > strtotime('2012-08-17') ) 
// I prefer to use "mktime" than "strtotime" for performance reasons
```

you may want to write your own validation method  or convert those dates to integers before validation.

**EDIT**

add this to your model class

```
public function rules () {
    array('due_date', 'isDueDateGreater'),
}

public function isDueDateGreater($attribute, $params) {
    if( strtotime($this->due_date) < strtotime($this->invoice_issue_date) ) 
        $this->addError('due_date', 'Due Date must be greater then Invoice Issue Date.');
}
```